# Adding usrfield to POLink grid POLine3 PXProjection

Tags: acumatica

I am attempting to add a usrfield from POOrderExt to the grid on SOOrderEntry->POLink. I tried to add a new field through the customizer (it attempted to create the field in Data Class: SO.POLine3).

```
[PXDBDate(BqlField = typeof(POOrderExt.usrFactDate))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Factory Confirmed", Enabled = false)]
```

[image: error message from customizer]

it fails, I recognize this is technically equivalent to a SQL view due to the PXProjection so it won't have a dedicated DAC. Is there a way I can append the POLine3 implementation to include my extension class, or do I have to create an entirely new serializable and change the grids Datamember?

Edit: I have implemented the Dac extension

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO{
public class POLine3Ext: PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.POLine3>{



        #region UsrCustomField


        [PXString][PXUIField(DisplayName="Custom Field")]
        public virtual string UsrCustomField{get;set;}
        public abstract class usrCustomField : IBqlField{}

    #endregion

   #region UsrFactoryConfirmedDate
    [PXDBDate]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "FactoryConfirmedDate")]

    public virtual DateTime? UsrFactoryConfirmedDate { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrFactoryConfirmedDate : IBqlField { }
   #endregion



}}
```

Here is my field defaulting event for my user field

```
    protected virtual void POLine3_UsrFactoryConfirmedDate_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
    {
        POLine3 row = (POLine3)e.Row;
        if (row == null) return;
        POLine3Ext rowE = PXCache<POLine3>.GetExtension<POLine3Ext>(row);

        POOrder pRow = PXSelect<POOrder, Where<POOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Required<POLine3.orderNbr>>>>
                            .Select(Base, row.OrderNbr);
        POOrderExt pRowExt = PXCache<POOrder>.GetExtension<POOrderExt>(pRow);

        if (pRow == null) return;
        e.NewValue = pRowExt.UsrFactoryConfirmedDate;
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

As I have mentioned in the comment below in Hybriddzz post, there is ***a operand data type null is invalid for max operator*** when i create the PXDBDate field. It won't let me open the POLink action to view the grid.

Comment: also, can you check in your project, whether there is an entry added for the table? if then it might need to be removed.

Open your project > File > Edit Project Items > Check for entry type 'Table' and Object name 'POLine3'

Comment: The customizer did create an entry, I ended up deleting it since it was causing errors.

Comment: Currently I'm creating the extension class manually like you've mentioned and testing it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an extension yourself for the DAC POLine3.

Refer to the HELP > Customization > Examples of Func Customization > Adding Data Fields > Adding a Data Field From Code

**Adding a Data Field From Code**

If you work with the customization code in MS Visual Studio, you can define a new data field in DAC extension code and then create the control on the form.

Comment: It seems like when i try to create a PXDBDate field in the extension DAC i get an error "Operand data type NULL is invalid for max operator." If i change it to the unbound version PXDate it'll work and i can add it to the grid. Unfortunately I'm trying to field default that date from another custom date field on PO and this is a hurdle I have not been able to figure out.